# How to write the following SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am on a MYSQL DB with the following schema.

```
id bigint(20)
url varchar(500)
timestamp datetime
server varchar(500)
```

I need to write a query  to find all which url gets switched by two different servers in an hour or more.

So for instance if url1 gets served by server1 at 11:00 and gets served by server2 at 12:00 then it should be in the result, however if url2 gets served by server1 at 11:05 and by server2 at 11:30 then it should not be in the result.

Please find the sample fiddle here [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b613) . In this case the output should be `www.url2.com`.

Comment: Please provide sample table and expected output. Or create a fiddle

Comment: To create a fiddle, go to http://sqlfiddle.com/.  Cool site!

Comment: Edited to add a sample fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use `timestampdiff` function in a `where exists...subquery`:

```
select distinct url 
from sample s1
where exists (
     select url 
     from sample s2 
     where 
     s2.url=s1.url
     and timestampdiff(HOUR, s2.timestamp, s1.timestamp)>=1
    )
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b613/3)